# Add layout to a promoted widget

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I can't add a layout to a widget that I have promoted to QWebEngineView. When I right-click MainWindow in object inspector and choose "Lay out" -> "Lay out vertically", the centralWidget gets a layout and the red flag disappears from the icon. The webEngineView inside the centralWidget still has the red flag in its' icon. If I right-click webEngineView and choose "Lay out", all options are greyed out.

I think the red flag is the reason why my QWebEngineView doesn't show up when I run the program.

How do I add a layout to webEngineView?

[image: Layout problem]

Comment: Check the parent (`centralWidget`) and scroll down through its properties. See if applying a layout to `centralWidget` does anything.

Comment: CentralWidget already has a layout in its' properties. And if I right-click it in Object inspector, there is no "Lay out" option.

Comment: Hi, I was able to apply a layout by temporarily placing another widget (e.g. PushButton, CheckBox) inside the webEngineView widget then applying a layout there. If I remove the PushButton/CheckBox, the layout to webEngineView will remain there.

Comment: This works. However, now the application output panel says: "QLayout: Attempting to add QLayout "" to QWebEngineView "webEngineView", which already has a layout". Also, QWebEngineView still doesn't show up. I did notice that it does show a web page if I run the program as a release version. If I run the program as a debug version, the webEngineView turns gray and doesn't show a web page.

Comment: I also tried running the program in debug mode with command line arguments "--disable-gpu --remote-debugging-port=1234 --no-sandbox" with no help. With an argument "--single-process" the program just crashes. This seems like a some kind of bug. My Qt version is 5.11. Would you mind making somekind of answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: To anyone interested: I finally solved my original problem by going back to Qt 5.9.7. There appears to be a problem viewing a web page in QWebEngineView with Qt 5.11.2 precompiled binaries in debug mode. The red flag in the icon in object inspector had nothing to do with it.